# When Java 6 will be dropped will my application continue to work?

Tags: java

I am a bit worried about something and no matter how much i searched i could not find something or i could not search properly.

I have an application that runs on java 6 SE. Oracle mentions in the website that they will drop the Java 6 SE Deployment in June 2017. So that leaves me with a question. Will my application still run after the Java 6 end or will it crash?

> Deployment Technology for Java SE 6 will be available until Jun 2017

Mentioned [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html)

Comment: Of course it will still run. It's not like Oracle hacks into your server and disables your java from running. By "dropping" Java 6 they mean that it will have no more updates and they no longer support it.

Comment: they stopped public updates since 2013

Comment: And there is also no time bomb implemented in the Java 6 JRE that looks at the current date and refuses to work if it is after June 2017.

Comment: You realize, of course, that both JDK 6 and 7 have passed the end of their support lives.  JDK 8 is the production version; JDK 9 is in flight.  You ought to plan to upgrade to JDK 8 as soon as possible.  Don't think you're doing anyone a favor by remaining on JDK 6.

Comment: of course and i realize that and i want to upgrade but my boss does not so i really need to know what is going to happen after a long time

Comment: Your boss has to be told that an upgrade is necessary.  Inform him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Will my application still run after the Java 6 end or will it crash?

It will continue to run.

- If a user downloads and installs a Java 6 JRE / JDK, your application will run as before.
- If a user has Java 7, Java 8, Java 9 .... etcetera, your application will run on those platforms *provided* that it is properly written.  Things that might cause it to break include:

  - dependencies on restricted "internal" classes that have been changed or removed in a later release,
  - incorrectly written multi-threaded code that breaks due to platform differences,
  - a tiny number of documented incompatibilities, and
  - dependencies on 3rd-party libraries that have not been ported.

However ....

You *ought to* take the time to port your application to run on the latest version of Java.  This is probably just a matter of compiling the codebase on the newer / newest Java JDK, and then running all of your unit and system tests.  (But if you have extensive dependencies on old libraries that are no longer being maintained, then you may have a problem ...)

If you don't do this, your application is liable to become problematic for users who won't **or cannot** install an out-of-date (and probably insecure!) version of Java on their systems.

This is even more important for applications that depend on web deployment and Java plugins for browsers.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. **No**. **Maybe**.

If you continue to use old JVM nothing will changes. Except you won't get bugfixes and security patches.

If you migrate to new JVM then in theory all should be fine (Java declare backward compatibility), but sometimes problems may occur. That's why you need to test you application with new JVM before you go into production.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by some of the others, yes your application will still work. It just means they will be done supporting it.

Answer (score 1):

## Oracle’s poor wording is ambiguous

To answer the specific part of your question, let's look at the text of the Oracle page, [*Oracle Java SE Support Roadmap*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html) (retrieved 2016-10).

> Support of Deployment Technology
>
> The web deployment technology, consisting of the Java Plugin and Web Start technologies, has a shorter support lifecycle. For all major releases of Java SE starting with Java SE 7, Oracle provides five (5) years of Premier Support for these technologies. Extended Support is not available for the deployment stack. See the Oracle Lifetime Support Policy for details.
>
> Deployment Technology for Java SE 6 will be available until Jun 2017.

This says that for (a) the [Java Plugin](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141438.html) for [Java applet](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet) and for (b) [Java Web Start](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) specifically you cannot purchase additional technical support from Oracle beyond 2017-06.  Other Oracle extended support contracts running beyond that date do not include technical support for the Java SE 6 version of this pair of deployment technologies.

That last sentence is poorly worded. I believe we can assume it should have begun with “Technical support for”. I understand the cause for your Question here.

As others have said, Oracle has never time-bombed any Java technology product nor have they ever announced any plans for doing so.

Oracle support for the plugin and for applets is practically moot as various operating systems and web browsers in recent years have been limiting or ending their support for Java applets due to security vulnerabilities. Java Web Start remains a viable platform for distributing local Java apps, though I recommend such apps move to later versions of Java.